# How to fetch (read) the value of the attribute of the tag in xml using libxml2 in C language

Tags: c, parsing, libxml2

following is snippet of my xml

```
<product id="1650379193">
  <feature id="37515"/>
</product>
```

here I want to fetch the value of attribute id in both cases one of product and other for feature .
How to do this using libxml2 in C language.

Comment: libxml2 seems to have an informative web site with a lot of documentation. Did you look there? Maybe the lack of answers to your questions here on SO is just because people don't want to do your "homework"? Voting to close the question as too localized.

Comment: You might start carving here: http://www.xmlsoft.org/examples/index.html

Comment: It's not too localized. But there's no research effort and no benefit for the community, so I'd close as well and downvote. I already answered several similar questions giving links to the documentation and samples.

Comment: I apologize for the comment I gave several days ago. Now I noticed a real problem in reading an attribute of a node. It should be done with `xmlGetProp`. How could one guess this name? If I could, I would reopen this question and provide a direct answer as this question seems to be unique and beneficial.

Comment: I found a similar question, although it was formerly marked as "iPhone". I edited it to reflect its general nature. [The link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1092227/772981).